# A ledger to note buying and selling of equities

Tags: stocks, record-keeping

I was wondering if there are any ledgers to make such entries. I trade regularly and I would like to make a good record of it.

Comment: You can get accounting software to records your trades, use spreadsheets to record them online, or record your trades in a paper notebook. All of these could be considered some kind of ledger. Is there something specific you're looking for?

Comment: Your broker may also provide something

Comment: Oops, typo: *to record*, not *to records*.

Comment: @Lawrence yes. I am looking for a ready made ledger that has designated columns for date, equity name, bought on, quantity, total buying value, sold on, qty, selling value, total profit/loss. I know that I can maintain a spreadsheet, but I am looking for a ledger exclusively. I am more comfortable with it. I assumed that these ledgers are commonly available as general purpose ledgers. Aren't they?

Comment: @Sara Have a look at the Asset functionality of common accounting packages. The free package *gnucash* even includes "stock" as one of its account types. Creating such an account brings up a register with columns like *shares, price buy, sell*. If this is of interest, I might post an answer when I have some time to collate it properly.

Comment: @Lawrence that would be of great help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The shareware software, KBH Investor Accounting, accounts both long and short positions and computes an overall mark-to-market accounting. The realized transactions can be printed out in the form of an IRS 4797 but assumes that no long term positions are included to make that form.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic.

Comment: I think the subject is asking for a software or product recommendation.

Comment: @Sara - Tradelog and Gainskeeper are two popular software programs that reconcile trades.  I have used Tradelog.  It handles all kinds of securities, multiple accounts, properly accounts for wash sales and prepares  Form 8949 for IRS Schedule D.  There is also a MTM version for those with Trader Tax Status. Analytical features let you see performance all year long as well as EOY.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Asset functionality of common accounting packages. It allows you to record prices and quantities of 'things' at purchase and sale. For shares, each stock code can be considered a separate 'thing' with buy and sell prices and quantities held in 'inventory'.

Each accounting package has its own processes and it takes awhile to become familiar with them. Here are some steps to get you started with gnucash, which is "[personal and small-business financial-accounting software, freely licensed under the GNU GPL](https://www.gnucash.org/)". (Disclaimer: I've starting using the software fairly recently, but I'm not otherwise knowingly affiliated with gnucash.)

1. Download and install [gnucash](https://www.gnucash.org/docs/v3/C/gnucash-guide/invest-setup1.html).
2. Open gnucash and Select menu item File -> New File. If a dialog pops up asking you to save changes to the (default) file, select "Continue Without Saving". This brings up the New Account Hierarchy Setup dialog.
3. Fill in whatever you like until you reach "Choose accounts to create". Here, select "Investment Accounts" for some defaults to start you off. Carry on with the rest of the dialog.
4. You'll be asked to save the file. Pick a filename you like, such as "Shares 2018". Pick a location (directory or folder), but be aware that gnucash will save lots of temporary and backup files in the same location. The filename you pick will be the main file, and once you quit gnucash, the rest can usually be safely deleted. However, you might want to keep them as backups. Make sure you click "Save" often (see the menu ribbon below the "File" menu) to ensure that your main gnucash file is up to date.
5. After saving, you'll see the chart of accounts. Here's a [link](https://www.gnucash.org/docs/v3/C/gnucash-guide/chapter_invest.html) to the gnucash manual for the chapter called "Investments". Follow [the instructions](https://www.gnucash.org/docs/v3/C/gnucash-guide/invest-setup1.html) to set up your investment portfolio, then use the manual for further instructions about buying and selling shares, recording dividends, and so on.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easy to set up a spreadsheet that records trades and reconciles the gains and losses.  It becomes more time consuming if you trade frequently and scale in and out of positions.  And it gets onerous if your trading involves numerous wash sales.

AFAIK,  US brokers provide Forms 1099-B and 8949 that break down of all of this.  The few that I've dealt with provide a disclaimer to the effect of:

> This is important tax information and is being furnished to the Internal Revenue Service. This statement has been prepared in accordance with our records, is provided for information purposes only and is not intended to constitute tax advice which may be relied upon to avoid penalties under any federal, state, local or other tax statutes or regulations, and does not resolve any tax issues in your favor. Please review it carefully for errors. It may or may not represent the amount of gain or loss reportable by you for Federal and state income tax purposes. We recommend that you consult your tax adviser as to the correct reporting of these items on your income tax return.

So the gist of it is that your broker prepares these forms, reports the results to the IRS yet disavows accuracy.  I can attest that if you're a frequent flier, broker reporting  often contain errors.  Some of the more well known software offering differing levels of expertise are Gainskeeper, Quicken, and Tradelog.

Comment: US 1099-B is provided only after the end of the year (normally next Jan 31, sometimes even later); 8949 is not provided at all, it is part of your return, where the data from 1099-B and some other sources is copied, grouped, and if necessary corrected.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - The general idea is that if you believe that your broker correctly reports your trades then you don't have to do anything during the year.  The 1099-B (yes, we know it's provided early the following year) will contain all of the information.  And you are incorrect about the 8949 not being provided at all.  Perhaps yours doesn't but mine provides it.  If for some reason you want to analyze your trading along the way, the professional tax programs will download the info from your broker whenever you want during the current year.

Answer (score 1):

Since softwares are being recommended I can post my comment as an answer:

The shareware software, KBH Investor Accounting, accounts both long and short positions and computes an overall mark-to-market accounting. The realized buy/sell transactions can be printed out in the form of an IRS 4797 but assumes that no long term positions are included to make that form. Most investors do not use a 4797 but might want the print-out.

For most investors, the overall mark-to-market accounting is not a tax accounting but a portfolio performance accounting.

Note that editing of an accounting is done by installing the back-up files. But the original files, with a time stamp, are also kept in the folder.